# Python - Group rows in list in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, group-by

> I have a dataframe like this:
>
> ```
> long  lat      Place 
> -6.779       61.9     Aarhus  
> -6.790     62.0       Aarhus      
> 54.377     24.4       Dhabi   
> 38.834     9.0        Addis 
> 35.698     9.2        Addis
> ```
>
> ```
>     Is it possible to transform the dataframe into a format like below?
>
> Office    long + lat
> Aarhus     [[-6.779,61.9], [-6.790,62.0]]
> Dhabi      [[54.377]]
> Addis      [[38.834,9.0], [35.698,9.2]]
> ```
>
> I tried different methods but still couldn't work this out. This is
>   what I tried to get a list for each distinct place value:
>
> ```
> df2["index"] = df2.index
> df2["long"]=df2.groupby('index')['long'].apply(list)
> list 1= [] 
> for values in ofce_list:
>     if df['Office'].any() == values:
>         list1.append(df.loc[df['Office'] == values, 'long'])
>
>     But this returned a series in a list instead which is not desired. Please help. Thank you so much.
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 df.groupby('Place')[['long','lat']].apply(lambda x :x.values.tolist()).\
      reset_index(name='long + lat')
Out[1380]: 
    Place                       long + lat
0  Aarhus  [[-6.779, 61.9], [-6.79, 62.0]]
1   Addis   [[38.834, 9.0], [35.698, 9.2]]
2   Dhabi     [[54.376999999999995, 24.4]]
```

Comment: Don't forget the `.reset_index(name='long + lat')`